# Get SUM of database 'amount' column

Tags: php, laravel

I have table columns `date`, `status` and `amount` in my database. So I want to query for sum of between two dates like start date and end date with particular date wise amount. but one problem if date like this '`2019-03-27`' to '`2019-04-25`' it means get last 30 days date wise sum of all records of `amount` field which has status of '`Winner`'. When month is differ in both of date at that time problem occur. i want that all for this graph https://prnt.sc/ngq5ky

```
<?php
if($dt_static == "Last_30_Days"){ 
    $Target_Arch_Graph = [];
    $cd = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dt_endDate)->format('d');                       
    $d = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dt_startDate)->format('d'); 
    $m = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $dt_startDate)->format('m');                       
    for($k = $d;$k<= $cd; $k++)
    {   
        if($k== 0)
        {
            $d = 0;                                   
            $m++;
        }
        $Get_Target_Arch_Graph = DB::table('bid_project')
        ->where('bid_project.status', '=', 'Winner')
        ->where('bid_project.date','=', date('Y-'.$m.'-'.$d))              
        ->sum('amount');
        $Target_Arch_Graph[] = json_decode('['.$d++.','.$Get_Target_Arch_Graph.']', true); 
    }                        
}
```

Comment: Have you defined models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same with Eloquent, but not knowing your models, here is a solution for using the query builder:

```
DB::table('bid_project')
    ->where('status', 'Winner')
    ->whereBetween('date', [$dt_startDate, $dt_endDate])              
    ->sum('amount');
```

If your dates are already formated as `Y-m-d` then you just need to pass them in the array above. Or pass them as Carbon instances and all should be good.

Answer (score 0):

if this will always be the case, you can make this query a bit more "eloquent":

In the your_model_name.php model:

```
   public function scopegetAmoutByDate($fromDate, $toDate)
   {
     return   DB::table('bid_project')
             ->where('status', 'Winner')
             ->whereBetween('date', array($fromDate, $toDate))              
             ->sum('amount')
             ->get();

   }
```

Then, to call this method from a controller:

```
ModelName::getAmoutByDate('2019-03-15', '2019-03-18');
```

Just prefix getAmoutByDate() with scope. This will become scopegetAmoutByDate().

Now you can call it from anywhere like ModelName::getAmoutByDate().